# (load) and (error) being called multiple time on img element angular4

Tags: angular

i am using angular 4 and have an image tag that should have a placeholder at first and when image is loaded the image changes but if there's an error the placeholder image is there .

this is my code

```
<img src="/assets/img/placeholder.jpg" 
 (error)="imageError($event)" 
             (load)="loadImage($event, image)"
             class="offer-img-mobile img-fluid" >



imageError(event) {
    event.target.src = '/assets/img/placeholder.jpg';
  }
  loadImage(event, image) {
    event.target.src =  image.imageurl;
  }
```

The issue that is arising now is that load and error are being called multiple times so the images keep toggling between the error image and images load(which throws error hence they arent visible)

[attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IOmn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `load` and `error` methods on image you can simply do using binding like this

```
<img [src]="image.imageurl || '/assets/img/placeholder.jpg'" 
class="offer-img-mobile img-fluid" >
```

This will wait for the image to load from the server meanwhile it will show your placeholder image.

Comment: but the issue with this is when image throws error  there is no placeholder just that icon

Comment: So you can handle error/exception by using some method and return image/placeholder image via that function